# How can I fix filtering and save as problem

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and  trying to write a macro, that filters by "Country", then copies it, creates new document, paste it there and save file based on "ID".

I keep getting

> run-time error 1004 its sorry we couldn't find... or microsoft can't access the file

Can anyone help? that the code I've got

```
Sub filter()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As Range
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim last As Long
    Dim sht As String
    Dim ID As String
    
    ID = Range("a2")
    
    'specify sheet name in which the data is stored
    sht = "Master"
    
    'change filter column in the following code
    last = Sheets(sht).Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Sheets(sht).Range("A1:Y" & last)
    
    Sheets(sht).Range("H1:H" & last).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range("AA1"), Unique:=True
    
    For Each x In Range([AA2], Cells(Rows.Count, "AA").End(xlUp))
        With rng
            .AutoFilter
            .AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=x.Value
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    
            Workbooks.Add
            ActiveSheet.Paste
    
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs filename:=Environ("userprofile") & "\OneDrive - \Desktop\VBA macro\ split by country" & ID & ".xlsm"
    
            ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End With
    Next x
    
    ' Turn off filter
    Sheets(sht).AutoFilterMode = False

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error? Did you check your path? Why is there a `-` behind `\OneDrive - \ ` ? Does  this file name `\ split by country` really start with a space? Please be more precise.

Comment: Its the line, that starts with Activeworkbook.savecopy as. As for the (-) sign there is an username after the hyphen. As for the  \ split by country. There is no space there,

Comment: Then please [edit] your code and show how that path really looks like. Because this is the issue we need to know exactly what it is. So there is something wrong with the path / file name (at least that is what your error tells you). Also check that this path really exists on your computer. Also tell us the exact value of `ID`.